# metafunction overload C++ - enable_if

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Let's say I want to have 2 meta functions named multiplicate. Those metafunctions should operate on vector types.

- One metafunction should take as input two vectors and multiply one value by another
- Another one should take as input one vector and scalar and multiply all values in vector by scalar.

The code I would like to have compilabe:

```
template <int V1, int V2, int V3...>
struct vector_c{
    enum{
        v1 = V1,
        v2 = V2,
        v3 = V3,
        ///
    };
};

template <typename Vector1, typename Vector2>
struct multiplicate{
   typedef /* do stuff */ type; 
};

template <typename Vector1, int value>
struct multiplicate{
    typedef /* do stuff */ type;
};
```

The thing is, that this code won't compile. I thought of doing somehing like:

```
template <typename Vector1, typename Vector2,
    typename enable_if_c<is_vector<Vector2>::value, int>::type =0>
    struct multiplicate{
       typedef /* do stuff */ type; 
    }; //should be fine

template <typename Vector1, int value,
    typename enable_if_c // what now? >
 struct multiplicate{
     //stuff
 };
```

The thing is, that in the second case I cannot put anything to enable_if, as 
value is not a type but it's already a value of type int. How can make this code working?

Comment: You may replace `int value` by `integral_constant` to have 2 types in both cases.

Comment: if I have some integral_constant, then I cannot do anything like vector_value * integral_constant. That's why I didn't do it

Comment: Not sure exactly what is meant. Do you mean `std::vector`? If so, how can it be modified at compile time? If not, what's the difference between vector and array in your terminology?

Comment: @YamMarcovic I clarified this in a post. Thanks.

Comment: @DawidPi: Why you can't do `vector_value * integral_constant` ?

Comment: because then integral_constant is a type as I understand? So I cannot multiply type and type

Comment: `vector_c<4, 5>` is also a type.

Comment: I propose something like: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4594710eb98174ed).

Comment: Do you want `multiplicate<vector_c<4, 5>, 42>` or `multiplicate<vector_c<4, 5>, int>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use template specialization, not two different templates.

```
//Primary template forward declaration
template<typename Vector1, typename Vector2, typename Enable = void>
struct multiplicate;

//specialization when is_vector<Vector2> is true
//leave second argument of enable_if with default value!!!
template<typename Vector1, typename Vector2>
struct multiplicate<Vector1, Vector2,
    typename enable_if<is_vector<Vector2>::value>::type>
{ //do the stuf
};

//specialization when Vector2 is exactly type int
template<typename Vector1, typename Vector2>
struct multiplicate<Vector1, Vector2,
    typename enable_if<is_same<Vector2, int>::value>::type>
{ //do the stuf
};

/* Declaration for any other case! 
   when you comment it (or delete), compilation fails 
   for other types of Vector2 with error: incomplete type */
template<typename Vector1, typename Vector2, typename Enable>
struct multiplicate
{ //do the stuf
};
```

Happy coding!