# Calling a static class method using a class type template

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I've seen questions about this with no definite answer if this is possible any other way/if it should be done differently. Say I have this:

```
template <typename T>
static T* SelfSpawn(UWorld* World, AActor* OwnerParam)
{
    if(!World)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    FActorSpawnParameters Params = FActorSpawnParameters();
    Params.Owner = OwnerParam;
    T* ThisActor = World->SpawnActorDeferred<T>(T::StaticClass(), FTransform(FRotator(0.f, 90.f, -90.f)));

    AActor* NewActor = UGameplayStatics::FinishSpawningActor(ThisActor, FTransform(FRotator(0.f, 90.f, -90.f)));

    return Cast<T>(NewActor);
}
```

T::StaticClass() will throw an error because it doesn't know for sure if T will be a class type. My question is, is there anyway to do template specialization or anything like that to guarantee that T is a class type so that this will work?

Comment: Add `static_assert(std::is_class<T>::value, "T must be of class type");`. Use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` if you don't have a C++11 compiler.

Comment: Yes, you can use template class specialization, your question is possibly [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130509/metafunction-overload-c-enable-if/35131414#35131414). Even the static_assert solution of @Paretorian will be enough to achieve it.